# R: Will the packages sp and rgdal still work after October?

Tags: r, rgdal

I am currently working on my master thesis and have a code in R that uses the packages sp and rgdal. These packages will be retired in october. Since I unfortunately don't have time to adapt all the code to newer packages like sf, I would like to know if it is still possible in or after October to use these packages if I already have them installed and don't do any updates?
Since the completion of my master thesis depends on it, it would be very important for me to know and I would be very grateful for an answer!
If this is not possible, could someone give me a hint where I can get a simple and accurate description on how to use Docker.
With kind regards
Leo

I have already added

```
options ("sp_evolution_status"=2)
```

in my code so that sp does not refer to rgdal.

Comment: Code will not "stop" to work. Of course it continues to run.  But the underlying packages will not longer _be on CRAN_ so no new downloads from there after the date.  It has all been detailed quite extensively in multiple blog posts you may have seen.

Comment: In seeing some of the sp migration code, if possible sp functions will be translated to sf in the backgound and will still run. This will facilitate backwards compatibility of sp objects without having to revert R version. Think of them as sf alias functions. However, the sp S4 object structure will not longer be supported. The rgeos, rgdal and maptools packages will no longer be available on CRAN. If you do not update packages, nothing will "stop working".

Comment: Furthermore, even if you do accidentally update some part of your sp toolchain, the CRAN Package Archive will maintain a copy of any old packages. As long as the version of R and other packages are of similar dates of issue you could restore an image. You should be using sessionInfo() at the beginning of each session to document versions. I think Dirk wrote a package called packrat that lets you maintain a working "image" of any desired snapshot in time..

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers! This is really helpful. So I can still use both sp and rgdal if I don't do any updates. 
I have a question about the sp S4 object structure that Jeffrey Evans mentioned. How does this affect me if the sp s4 object structure is no longer supported?